# Is it possible to communicate two networks without being dual nat?

Tags: networking, router, nat

I have two separate networks, at two different locations, each with there own internet, connected with a nanobridge(lan/lan). I have both networks set statically so that they aren't always crossing the bridge and connecting to the wrong router. I don't know much about this but is it possible to set up this network so that it's not dual nat? Because of this issue, my icam sources keep getting lost trying to find there way out of the network is the reason.
thx Jace

- The reason is just when the networks are connected my icam sources switch to saying "upnp dual nat" and communication with them becomes very unreliable. I don't know all the scenarios of dual nat, but I assumed maybe since there's no static setup for icam that it was trying to communicate with both routers and getting confused or if this is a totally different issue?
  thx

Comment: just to clarify, by 'nanobridge' you are referring to a point-to-point wireless bridge, and there is no router between the networks when they cross the bridge?

Comment: correct, basically just a wireless ethernet cable.

Comment: I'm not getting why this is a dual nat scenario then. from any single devices perspective, there is a local default gateway to the internet (1 NAT) and a non-Nat bridge to the the other network. if communications moved out of network A's gateway, across the internet, and into network B's gateway, then that would involve 2 Nat barriers, but as you describe it, that should not happen. could you please clarify on why you believe you are facing dual nat operation?

Comment: It's happening because it's just one site and `SSDP` finds both NATs and don't know what to do. Is there a reason for one subnet? You may reslove this either by setting up propper routing or blocking udp `port 1900` on `nanobridge`.

Comment: Hey thx. I didn't even think about being able to block ports through the bridge. I can assign ports to the icam sources so I will look into figuring out my nanobridges firewall. If this works is there anything wrong with leaving subnets the same?